# How to style data that is extracted from localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am displaying data from localstorage but the problem is it doesn't have any formatting so everything is jumbled together. Is there something I can do to style it?

I am getting these values like this -

```
function getItem() {
    const item = localStorage.getItem('name');
    return document.getElementById('favsarray').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(item);
}
getItem()
```

Comment: Can you share your relevant html and maybe a screenshot illustrating how everthing is jumbled together?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` can produce "pretty printed" output if you supply an indent value. You can check the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for details.